# How to take backup of Previous Versions in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, backup, archiving, volume-shadow-copy, vss

Windows 7 keeps an archive of the `Previous Versions` of files using its `Volume Shadow-Copy Service (VSS)`.

How can I take a backup or image of the `Previous Versions` archive for a specific folder?

Comment: The Crashplan backup software uses the Volume Shadow-Copy service to backup files which are in use which suggests what you want to do is possible. Are you looking for software to do this for you?

Comment: @Richard: Unless I'm mistaken, looks like he want to back up *all* the Previous Versions of a folder.